# Batch convert all files in a directory with spaces in filename

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I've done this batch file that should convert all mp3 files in given folder but, I dont know why, it doesn't work...

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
title Converting...

set fold=C:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\
set ext=*.mp3
set dest=C:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\

for %%f in (%fold%%ext%) do ffmpeg -i %%f -b 192k %dest%%%f

pause>nul
exit
```

I think it's because of the spaces in the files names and in the folder name but i don't actually know... can someone verify and find out the right code?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy.

```
for %%f in ("%fold%%ext%") do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -b 192k "%dest%%%~nxf"
```

(modified version)

Here's my test batch

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL
REM title Converting...

set fold=U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\
set ext=*.mp3
set dest=U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\

:: This makes the directories, then creates two dummy files
:: only used for testing.

MD "%fold%"
MD "%dest%"
dir>"%fold%file1.mp3"
dir>"%fold%file two.mp3"

for %%f in ("%fold%%ext%") do ECHO ffmpeg -i "%%f" -b 192k "%dest%%%~nxf"
```

The `ECHO` in the last line is to show what would be executed. After verification, remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate the `FFMPEG` command.

`%%~nxf` is the name+extension of the file `%%f`

results:

```
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\file1.mp3" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file1.mp3"
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\file two.mp3" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file two.mp3"
```

Hmmm...perhaps you need to replace `USERNAME` when you're setting `FOLD` and `DEST` with `%username%`

---

revised to add processing for multiple filetypes

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL
REM title Converting...

set fold=U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\
set ext=*.mp3 *.wma *.m4a
set dest=U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\

:: This makes the directories, then creates dummy files

MD "%fold%"
MD "%fold%subdir"
MD "%dest%"
dir>"%fold%file1.mp3"
dir>"%fold%file two.mp3"
dir>"%fold%file3.wma"
dir>"%fold%subdir\file four.wma"

 for /r "%fold%" %%f in (%ext%) do ECHO ffmpeg -i "%%~ff" -b 192k "%dest%%%~nxf"
```

Noting that I haven't changed the `FFMPEG` command - you are aware of the parameters you require. Command echoed as usual.

If you want to use a constant output extension, say .MP3, change `"%dest%%%~nxf"` to `"%dest%%%~nf.MP3"`

Revised batch output:

```
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\file1.mp3" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file1.mp3"
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\file two.mp3" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file two.mp3"
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\file3.wma" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file3.wma"
ffmpeg -i "U:\Users\Username\Music\Music to convert\subdir\file four.wma" -b 192k "U:\Users\Username\Music\Converted Music\file four.wma"
```

Comment: Ok thank you very very much!
Just one last thing please... is there a way to read also subdirectories of this folder and to convert multiple filetypes?
Ex: I would do this 'ffmpeg -y -i input-file.ext -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 output-file.mp3' for
files with wma, m4a and mp3 extension in the directory and subdirectories.
Thank you for your time :)